# How do I display the current and total amount of slides - Featherlight.js

Tags: javascript, featherlight.js

How do  I display the current slide number and total slide count in my featherlight gallery?

```
<div class="thumbnail-gallery" >    
    <a class="gallery" href="#" data-featherlight="#1">
        Image 1
    </a>
    <div id="1" class="lightbox">
        <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>   
    <a class="gallery" href="#" data-featherlight="#2">
        Image 2
    </a>
    <div id="2" class="lightbox">
        <img src="image2.jpg" />
    </div>  
    // I would like to display slide number and total slide count here
    <p>Image <span class="current-slide">#</span> of <span class="total-slides">#</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The featherlight gallery class adds the `slides` method, which you can use for your purposes.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate a little on how to implement that?

Comment: Hi, would really appreciate a bit more guidance on this :)